# How do I avoid using eval on scripts from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, eval

My web app (running jQuery) gets the following JSON response from the server:

```
{
    "script_0": "$('#objview_0_306').on('click', function(e){ getObjectResponse(96089, '306', 'display'); e.preventDefault();});",    
    "verb_0": "display",
    "obid_0": "0_306",
    "body_0": "<div id=\"objview_0_306\"></div>",
    "icon_0": "icons/caseman16.png",
    "close_0": "previousTab();",
    "title_0": "Cases",
    "cmdCount": "1"
}
```

The script_0 element contains scripts that must be run, in this case adding an onClick event to a DOM element.

At the moment, I use eval() to run the scripts, since they are returned as strings. Is there a way to avoid using eval()?

Comment: Write your own js interpreter in js ... seriously though, why on earth would you have code in json? it's a **data** -interchange format...

Comment: Let's call it a novice mistake. This is a leftover from when I started programming 3 years ago.

Comment: Who has never done anything like that throw the first stone =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noop. The eval (and alias Function constructor etc.) is designed to do exactly this, parse strings into runnable javascript.

If you don't want to use `eval`, instead of return the complete javascript from the server, you can return values in json response that instruct your client app to do predefined tasks.

I'm going to plagiarize the comment made by @Esailija: 
Why on earth would you have code in json? it's a data-interchange format...

Comment: been there, done that...sometimes it's just easier and faster in terms of development time to have functions that depend on a lot of parameter, data in the DB etc.. selected and bootstrapped only in one place (on the server) than duplicate lot's of code client side.. of course, the clean approach would and should be to only pass data to the client and implement the handling there

Comment: For me it's very very hard to do things like this, seems unnatural or something...

Comment: yea, I always feel the need to take a long hot shower if I have to do something like this. Thank <higher being> it's very seldom necessary now that our projects have a better time frame

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can achieve what you want without `eval` or one of its derivates.

You could give a look to `jQuery.globalEval()` method, as described here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/

And you could also give a look to the `jQuery.getScript()` method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 0):

I'll be the first to spout the usual `eval == evil` mantra, but im also a realist, and there are times when rules can be broken.

I'd say you might have one of them here.

Comment: I'll keep it this way in the interim, but will eventually change it to only send data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to append that string with code to DOM and then trigger the click event on needed element.